# nodejs equivalent of PHPlivedocx?

Tags: php, node.js, livedocx

I was wondering if there is a nodejs equivalent of PHPlivedocx. Is there any open-source alternative to read MS office docs (docx,pptx,xlsx) in nodejs (what about PHP?). I want to integrate it with a large scalable web app.

Answer (score 2):

PHPlivedocx it's a wrapper to call the SOAP api of LiveDocX. I think you could just use a SOAP library for node.js to call the same service.

Answer (score 2):

A new node module has just been released. See https://github.com/kingsquare/node-livedocx .